# SQL Query multiple parameter in a query string but only must must be executed

Tags: sql

I have two parameters, @ID and @Name, I also have 2 seperate input field for them, only one of them must only be executed, the only one that will be executed is the not empty, or if you have an idea of other ways of doing this, please help

Sample query string:

```
"SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @ID or name = @Name"
```

My query string:

```
select 
i.ssn_or_tin,
x.name,
i.cusid,
x.account_no,
i.dateTrans,
i.transCode,
d.TransDesc,
i.transdescription_1,
i.debit_or_credit,
coalesce((case when i.debit_or_credit = 'Dr' then i.debit end),0) as Debit,
coalesce((case when i.debit_or_credit = 'Cr' then i.debit end),0) as Credit,
(coalesce(c.debit,0))as cashin,
i.source 
from source_ips i left join 
(select distinct * from source_cash_in_original where  transCode ='966') as c on (i.ssn_or_tin =c.ssntin and i.cusid=c.cusid and i.accountNo = c.accountNo) and i.dateTrans=c.dateTrans and i.transCode='131' left join
(select distinct * from source_cash_out_original where  transCode ='936') as o on (i.ssn_or_tin =o.ssntin and i.cusid=o.cusid and i.accountNo = o.accountNo) and i.dateTrans=o.dateTrans and i.transCode='131' left join
TransDescriptions d on i.transCode = d.TransCode
left join (select a.customer_id,a.account_no,d.ssn_or_tin,a.name from customer_account a left outer join customer_data d on a.customer_id =d.customer_id)as x on i.ssn_or_tin = x.ssn_or_tin and i.cusid=x.customer_id and i.accountNo = x.account_no
where (i.ssn_or_tin = @ssn_or_tin or @ssn_or_tin is null or x.name = @name or @name is null) and i.dateTrans between '2014-12-01' and '2016-08-02' order by i.dateTrans ASC
```

Comment: what language are you using to handle SQL java, vb.net?

Comment: @JoeyPinto ASP.NET MVC

Comment: The empty string ('') is not the same as NULL. That SQL will work if the program NULL as the @ID/@Name value when the "input not to search" is the empty string.

Comment: I'd fix this on the client end... build the string to only send what you need in your C# or VB.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @NAME is null
( SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @ID ) ;
ELSE 
(SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = @NAME) ;
```

Comment: In a UDF (SQL function)

Comment: @Hanzou Nowhere. A tutorial and associated material should be read first: and then approach the problem when it is better defined. The "query string" and whatever is asked in the question are *two entirely different concepts*. Also, this answer add no semantic value; the reason why would be seen after reading an SQL tutorial.

Comment: With practicing the tutorial all the questions come to the answer but I think s/he still has the right to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The general purpose mechanism is:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM accounts a
WHERE a.id = @ID OR @ID IS NULL OR
      a.name = @Name OR @Name IS NULL;
```

Note.  If you have indexes on `id` and `name`, this this will not use them (probably).  Depending on the database, you may need to dynamic SQL to get use of the index in both cases (this is due to compiling the queries during the first run of the stored procedure).

Comment: I've updated my post with my query string, i tried your code but it's not working, please help